# How can I get the html form name from php with multiple file uploads?

Tags: php, html, forms

If I do something like this to get handle file uploads:

```
if ($_FILES) {
    foreach ($_FILES as $file) {
        //...Handle the upload process
    }
}
```

Is there any way that I can get the key of the file? As in:

```
<input type="file" name="myfile" />
```

I want to know that the file is coming from "myfile".

Edit: The obvious solution to this turns out to be:

```
foreach($_FILES as $key => $file) {

    $input_name = $key;
    // Handle upload.

}
```

Comment: In your HTML, I believe that you'll want to use <input type="file" name="myfile[]" /> (note the []) to make is easier to understand the multiple files.

Comment: Done. @eric, actually it's for multiple elements, if that makes sense. <input type="file" name="file1" /> <input type="file" name="file2" />

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the input name in your form is `myfile`, then it will be in the `$_FILES` array as:

```
$_FILES['myfile']
```

So you can do:

```
foreach ($_FILES as $inputName => $fileInfo) {

}
```

Check out [Handling file uploads](http://www.php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.php) for more info.

Comment: So I can actually do this?
list($key,$value) = each($_FILES)

Comment: yeah I get that, but specifically I want to have the key of the form input. So something like this

while(list($key,$file) = each($_FILES)){
echo 'the key is: ' . $key;
}

Comment: Yes that will work. `$key` will then contain the name your chose for your form input. I've also edited the answer to make it more clear with the foreach.